# AWS Athena access from Javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-athena

I am trying to connect Athena from Javascript SDK using unauthorized Cognito IAM role but I am getting AccessDenied Exception. With same set up I am able to access S3 and dynamodb.
I have provided privileges for S3 and Athena for pool role for unauth access.

```
Error: User: arn:aws:sts::11xxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/Cognito_Pool1Unauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: athena:StartQueryExecution

// A lot of useless lines

at constructor.callListeners (aws-sdk.min.js:2) "AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::11xxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/Cognito_Pool1Unauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: athena:StartQueryExecution
```

Is it that we can not connect Athena from Javascript using Cognito Unauthorised Pool Id? I thought we should be able to. Is there any other setting we need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems an issue with the role mapped through JS sdk. For Dynamo and other services it worked fine. By specifying the role with  permissions it works.